# Joining 3 or more tables in SQL Query, Getting Empty Array Back?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, syntax

Ok so after going over this multiple times I don't understand what I am missing

I have at the moment 3 tables:

Users Table:

```
ID | Username | Password
1  |   Micky  |   123
2  |   Mouse  |   145
```

Questions Table:

```
 Question ID| Question_Title   | Question      | Rating | Category ID | User ID |
     1      | Meaning of Life? | Same as Title |  100   |      2      |    1    |
     2      | Foo is love?     | Same as Above |   95   |      4      |    2    |
```

Answer Table:

```
   Answer_ID| Answer   | Answer_Rating     | Answer_User_ID    | Question_ID |
     1      | YES      |       1           |     1             |      1      |
```

And I have the following Query:

```
"SELECT u.username, 
q.Question_Title, 
q.Question, 
q.Rating, 
a.Answer,
a.Answer_Rating
FROM Questions q 
join Users u on u.id = q.User_ID
join Answers a on a.Question_ID = 'q.Question ID' 

WHERE q.Question_Title LIKE '%$Term%'";
```

This will get me the Username of the person who asked the question in addition to the Question Title, Question, Question Rating, Answer to the question and the Rating of the answer.

However what do i add to the query so that it will print out the username of the person who answered the question, via the foreign key Answer_User_ID?

No matter what I have tried, It will turn out empty, it will return the query in associative array and I am currently using print_r to display the array.

P.S: The table structure will grow and I would like to know if their is a consistent way of adding to the query to include fields and multiple foreign keys that will be added later.

Comment: You should not have single quotes in `on a.Question_ID = 'q.Question ID' `.

Comment: If I take that out, i wouldn't pick it up because their is a space in the name? without it gives me an error.

Comment: You want backticks, unless Codeigniter does something unusual.  As written in MySQL, it will interpret `'q.Question ID'` as a string, not a column reference.

Comment: Wait, I tried that too it didn't work I have no idea why. I remember trying the back ticks but it wouldn't accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another `join` to `users`:

```
SELECT u.username, q.Question_Title, q.Question, q.Rating, 
       a.Answer, a.Answer_Rating,
       ua.username as AnswerUserName
FROM Questions q join
     Users u
     on u.id = q.User_ID join
     Answers a
     on a.Question_ID = q.`Question ID` join
     Users ua
     on ua.id = a.Answer_User_ID
WHERE q.Question_Title LIKE '%$Term%'";
```

Comment: Thank You this worked, I assume it's the same as the table structure grows?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "as the table structure grows".  But, if you had other columns referring to users, you could join them in using additional references to the `Users` table.

Comment: For instance say I had another table which stored Reputation and had another foreign via user ID, if i did something like: join Reputation ar on ar.ID = u.id would that work?

Comment: You would want to join it to the appropriate user id.  I would suggest with `q.User_ID` or `a.Answer_User_Id` for clarity.  Then you would get the reputation record(s) for that particular user.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. It's a shame it's phpmyadmin makes it really hard to tell how to foreign keys are set up